# PHP preg_match get only complete matches

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to execute a preg_match to get the complete match of the pattern, and I don't need the sub-matches.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
$text = 'abc.php?v=2&amp;g=js';
// Pattern to check
$pattern_array = array('abc\.php\?v=\d+&(amp;)?g=js', 'xyz\.php');
$pattern = '/(' . implode('|', $pattern_array) . ')/i';
echo 'Pattern:' . $pattern . '<br />';
preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
if (!empty($matches)) 
{
    echo 'pattern found';
}
else
{
    echo 'pattern not found';
}
var_dump($matches);
```

I am getting the following output:

```
Pattern: /(abc\.php\?v=\d+&(amp;)?g=js|xyz\.php)/i
pattern found
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'abc.php?v=2&amp;g=js' (length=20)
  1 => string 'abc.php?v=2&amp;g=js' (length=20)
  2 => string 'amp;' (length=4)
```

However, I just want the output to be just the following from the matches array.

```
  0 => string 'abc.php?v=2&amp;g=js' (length=20)
```

Also, in case my $text matches multiple patterns, I want to be able to see all those patterns.

Comment: I dont understand why you are putting your pattern into a single element array and then trying to implode it.  Can you clarify your intent here? Also is your question simple trying to ask how to write `echo $matches[0]`?

Comment: I just updated the code. The reason, I am putting it in array is I want to be able to test multiple patterns, and see which pattern matches.

Comment: Why not just loop through the patterns or create your own function which does that and returns the matched pattern?  There is not a way to determine the pattern that is matched by inspecting the `$matches` result.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the groups as non capture, `(?:...)` instead of `(...)`:

```
$pattern_array = array('abc\.php\?v=\d+&(?:amp;)?g=js', 'xyz\.php');
//                                    ___^^
$pattern = '/(?:' . implode('|', $pattern_array) . ')/i';
//         ___^^
```